# Display math in \begin{array}

Tags: arrays

I have this LaTeX snippet:

```
\[
\begin{array}{lll}
a &- bold &= c \\
hold &+ y &= \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} z_i \\
\end{array}
\]
```

And it gives me:

[image: Funkyness]

However, I need the:

[image: Even funkier figure]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Add `\displaystyle` before `\sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} z_i`.

Comment: Well, that was quick! Thanks!

Comment: LaTeX typesets equations in `array` in `\texstyle` format, which by default uses a compact form of `\sum`. You could use `\limits` in `\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{n - 1} z_i` and maintain a smaller size of the `\sum` symbol (in text style) or as @Bernard suggested use `\displaystyle`

Comment: @Celdor Nice to know that too!

Comment: do not use array for equations, use an ams aligment such as `aligned` which is displaystyle by default and will give correct space around =. Also use `\mathrm{bold}`  or `\mathit{bold}` not bold.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Can’t. I need 3 columns, all left aligned, yet the aligned environment aligns the 3rd column on the right.

Comment: @user1049393 no: aligned (or here alignedat) can have as many columns as you need, every other column is left aligned so use `&&`  to skip the right aligned columnn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

`array` is designed for matrices and other tables of values. It uses `\textstyle` and does not give correct spacing for relations or binary operators. Your example shows this in `\sum` and the spacing for `-` and `+` as unary prefix with no space.

AMS alignments are designed to address these issues. Also avoid math italic for words, the default math font is designed to make adjacent letters look like  product of 1-letter variables. Use `\mathrm` (or `\mathit`if you want italic).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
 &a&&-\mathrm{bold}&&=c\\
 &\mathrm{hold}&&+y&&= \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} z_i 
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```